# API GET Fails When Retrieving Data from Dynamodb

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I can do a successful `PUT` request, but all my `GET` requests keep failing.
I either get the below if I specify a path parameter

```
"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema"%
```

Or I get the below when I try to get all items using `curl <link>`

```
{"message":"Internal Server Error"}%
```

Full code

```py
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table_name = 'my-table'
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)

key = {
    'id': {
        'S': '1'
    }
}

def handler(event, context):
    body = None
    status_code = 200
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    try:
        # Based on API Gateway Payload v2.0
        if event['routeKey'] == 'PUT /items':
            request_json = json.loads(event['body'])
            put = table.put_item(
                    Item=request_json
            )
            body = f"Put item with id: {request_json['id']}"

        # Get all items 
        elif event['routeKey'] == 'GET /items':
            scan = table.scan()
            items = scan.get('Items', [])
            body = items

        # Get an item based on the path parameter
        elif event['routeKey'] == 'GET /items/{id}':
            path_parameters = event['pathParameters']
            id_value = path_parameters['id']
            get = table.get_item(
                    Key={
                        'id': {
                            'S': id_value
                            }
                        }
                    )
            body = get.get('Item', None)

        # Delete an item based on the path parameter    
        elif event['routeKey'] == 'DELETE /items/{id}':
            id_value = path_parameters['id']
            delete = table.delete_item(
                Key={
                    'id': id_value
                }
            )
            body = f"Deleted item with id: {id_value}"

        else:   
            raise Exception(f"Unsupported route: {event['routeKey']}")
    except ClientError as e:
        status_code = 400
        body = str(e)
    finally:
        body = json.dumps(body)

    return {
        'statusCode': status_code,
        'body': body,
        'headers': headers,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using low-level DynamoDB JSON syntax with a high level client. Read more about this here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/

Change your syntax to standard JSON.

```
get = table.get_item(
                    Key={
                        'id':id_value   
                        }
                    )
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. I just fixed that part. However, I still get an “Internal Server Error”.